# How to avoid my code from being killed when it runs out of RAM

Tags: python

I am trying to run a code function that kills my code because it runs out of RAM. I can't optimise the way the code is written since it is a function from a package I don't own. Is there a way to allow the code to run (at a slower rate) without the code being killed?

Comment: In the general case, no. In the specific case, you'd need to explain which parts of memory can be swapped out, which means you do have to rewrite the code to tell the computer that.

Comment: What OS are you using? It may be possible to configure or disable the OOM killer on your system, though that might mean the whole computer crashes or becomes non-responsive when you start swapping more and more needed logic out of memory to make way for your runaway program. If the library function you're using is really so inefficient, you might need to write your own version of it that consumes less memory or run it on a smaller dataset.

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is the memory complexity of the algorithm you are using, can you change your inputs to have lower memory like using int8 instead of int64 or can you rewrite the algorithm, can you partially execute the algorithm in chunks and gather all the results? There is too much unknown to answer but the fix is probably not easy.

Comment: quick and dirty - given the info given - Google Colab could be a quick (temp) fix in the contingency.